# What shoulder straps are these?

Tags: uniform

To what uniform these shoulder straps belong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your source of pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on GIS (Google Image Search) hits, it is from nowadays Russia from [Bashkorostan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashkortostan). If you are familiar with Russian language, [here is the web site where](http://vedsimvol.mybb.ru/viewtopic.php?id=711) they provide extra information. Sadly I couldn't find English sources.

The same symbolics can be found on [Iglinckii rayon (Iglinsk county) wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iglinsky_District). Sadly the former original russian site was deleted.